# Parametric 3D plot with parameters satisfying an implicit equation

Tags: plotting

I am trying to plot a function $ {\bf x}(t) = r(t)\hat{v} + {\bf b}(t) $, with unit vector $ \hat{v} $ and vector $ {\bf b}(t) $ given in spherical coordinates. For simplicity, assume that $ \hat{v} = (\sin\theta\cos\phi, \sin\theta\sin\phi, \cos\theta) $, and $ {\bf b}(t) = [t, \sin(a+t), \cos(b + at^2)] $, where $ a $ and $ b $ are constants. This is easy to plot, however, I want the angles $ \theta $ and $ \phi $ to satisfy an implicit equation, say, $ \cos\theta + a(\phi + b t)^2 + c = 0 $.

Comment: This is kind of confusing. Is $\mathbf x$ a function of both $t$ and $\hat v$? What is the function $a(t)$? Is it different from the constant $a$? Are they both different from the $a$ in your last equation?

Comment: Sorry, that was a typo. It should have said $ r(t) $ instead of $ a(t) $. If it simplifies things, you can plot $ {\bf x}(t) $ as a function of $ \theta $ and $ \phi $ for fixed values of $ t $.

Comment: I guess you could define your desired surface as a 3D contour plot of $f(\theta,\phi,t) = 0$, transformed under the map $(\theta,\phi,t) \mapsto r(t)[\sin\theta\cos\phi,\sin\theta\sin\phi,\cos\theta]+\mathbf b(t)$. Unfortunately I don't know how to apply such a nonlinear transformation to a 3D plot.

Answer (score 2):

You can use an appropriately defined `MeshFunction` as per your constraint equation. For every `t` you should then get a line on the sphere. If you don't want the sphere to be visible you can change the opacity to zero in the relevant option. Here I've chosen the constants `a`, `b`, `c` so that the constraint equation has a solution:

```
 Manipulate[
 Module[{a = 1, b = -1, c = -2, r, AA, BB, constr, tolerance = 1},
  r[t_] := t;
  AA[θ_, ϕ_] := {Sin[θ] Cos[ϕ], Sin[θ] Sin[ϕ], Cos[θ]};
  BB[t_] := {t, Sin[a + t], Cos[b + a t^2]};
  constr = Function[{θ, ϕ}, Cos[θ] + a (ϕ + b t)^2 + c];
  ParametricPlot3D[r[t] AA[θ, ϕ] + BB[t],
   {θ, 0, 2 π},
   {ϕ, 0, π},
   MeshFunctions -> constr,
   Mesh -> {{0}},
   PlotRange -> {-10, 10},
   MeshStyle -> {Thick, Red},
   PlotStyle -> Opacity[0.7],
   PlotRange -> All]
  ], {t, -5, 5, .5}]
```

[image: constrained]

Answer (score 1):

As you have one constraint equation, your surface $\vec{x}(\theta,\phi,t)$ is in fact parametrized by two parameters only. In this simple case you could solve 
$$
\cos\theta+a(\phi+bt)^2+c=0
$$
and get
$$
\theta=\arccos(-a(\phi+bt)^2-c)
$$
Then, by inserting it in $\vec{x}$ you see that $\vec{x}=\vec{x}(\phi,t)$, which can now be readily plotted.